# Merge transparent PNG over a JPEG using PHP Imagick

Tags: php, opacity, imagick

I am using ImageMagick 7 along with PHP 5.6.30 and PECL Imagick 3.4.3.

Using the code below, I am trying to overlay a 50% transparent PNG over a JPEG image. The result is the PNG image overlays but without the transparency.

Any ideas?

```
<?php
    $im = new Imagick('base.jpg');
    $wm = new Imagick('watermark.png');
    $wm->setImageAlpha(0.5);
    $im->compositeImage($wm, Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0);
    $im->writeImage('final.jpg');
?>
```

Comment: I believe the constant you want is `COMPOSITE_OVER`. `COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY` should only copy the opacity channel from the image, not the entire image preserving opacity.

Comment: Using COMPOSITE_OVER makes the image transparent but without the opacity. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for me:

```
<?php
    $im = new Imagick('base.jpg');
    $wm = new Imagick();
    $wm->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
    $wm->readImage('watermark.png');
    $wm->setImageFormat('png32');
    $wm->setImageAlpha(0.5);
    $im->compositeImage($wm, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
    $im->writeImage('final.jpg');
?>
```